# URI::InvalidURIError while trying to download by URL with square brackets

Tags: ruby, uri, open-uri

I am currently trying to download the picture of this link:

```
http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/9/14-116.0/compressed/Bleach-14-116[manga-rain]._manga_rain_bleach_ch116_01.jpg
```

This generates a `URI::InvalidURIError` exception.

After reading around on Stack Overflow, I've tried ( but failed ):

```
uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(url.strip))

safeurl = URI.encode(url.strip)
```

I do know the issue has something to do with web browsers being more "friendly" but I do not know how to get my application to do the same.

Comment: Square brackets aren't allowed in a URI despite how some people insist on putting them in there. Try replacing them with `%5b` and `%5d` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sort of hack way of dealing with the invalid characters in the URL:

```
u = 'http://z.mfcdn.net/store/manga/9/14-116.0/compressed/Bleach-14-116[manga-rain]._manga_rain_bleach_ch116_01.jpg'
fixed = u.gsub(/[\[\]]/) { '%%%s' % $&.ord.to_s(16) }

open(fixed)
```

That should deal with this particular problem.

Comment: It makes the URL conform to proper standards. Browsers, as you've observed, are extremely lax about what can go in the path and query components.